# How to combine 2 functions containing a same subset of arguments with same values into 1 function?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm building a graph with Plotly (Python 3.6) which can either be a scatter plot or a bar chart depending on user entry. I realised that scatter plot require an additional argument and I want to avoid having to define both cases if possible as all other arguments would be the same.

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
```

Scatter plot:

```
data=go.Scatter(
x=x, 
y=y, 
mode='lines')
```

Bar chart:

```
data=go.Bar(
x=x, 
y=y)
```

Is there a way to combine both into a single function?

I've tried to use a function to determine which function to use, but cannot figure out how to determine whether or not to add the 3rd argument (mode). Here's my try:

```
if input == "Scatter":
   fct = go.Scatter
if input == "Bar":
   fct = go.Bar

data=fct(
x=x,
y=y)
```

How do I add the optional "mode"? I'd dream of something like that:

```
    data=fct(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    if input == "Scatter":
       mode="lines"
   )
```

Comment: do you know how to utilize, **kwargs?

Comment: now a bit more, thanks to the answer below !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `**kwargs` to achieve this. My example has `input` being replaced with `user_input`:

```py
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

N = 1000
x = np.random.randn(N)
y = np.random.randn(N)

user_input = "Bar"

if user_input == "Scatter":
    fct = go.Scatter
    fun_kwargs = {'mode': 'lines'} 
if user_input == "Bar":
    fct = go.Bar
    fun_kwargs = {}

fct(x=x, y=y, **fun_kwargs)
```

Output:

```py
Bar({
    'x': array([-0.51224629, -0.19486754,  0.04559578, ..., -2.47111604,  0.94998171,
                 1.09732577]),
    'y': array([ 2.0182325 ,  0.05311828,  0.63149072, ...,  0.65456449,  0.73614411,
                -1.02471641])
})
```

Now using "Scatter":

```py
user_input = "Scatter"

if user_input == "Scatter":
    fct = go.Scatter
    fun_kwargs = {'mode': 'lines'} 
if user_input == "Bar":
    fct = go.Bar
    fun_kwargs = {}

fct(x=x, y=y, **fun_kwargs)
```

Output:

```py
Scatter({
    'mode': 'lines',
    'x': array([ 1.3311512 ,  1.72058406, -1.11571885, ..., -0.66691056, -1.81278558,
                 0.75089731]),
    'y': array([-0.77526413, -0.06880226, -0.45198727, ..., -1.35639219, -0.16597244,
                -0.91315996])
})
```